# How to generate level for a laser game in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, generator

I am trying to generate a random level for my silly game. The game consists of having laser/detector pairs around a square field of possible mirrors. Like this:

```
/*

LLLLLLLLLL
LmmmmmmmmL
LmmmmmmmmL
LmmmmmmmmL
LLLLLLLLLL

*/
```

Now, I have an algorithm which generates a level, quite poorly, by relying on random placement, and rejecting bad positions. This is not very fast, and does not really generate the kind of fields I'd like to have. Please feel free to try it out at http://cmouse.desteem.org/laser/

Any suggestions are welcome.

The current algorithm looks something like this:

```
function createLevel:
  for i=0 to mirrors:
    mirrorLocation = pickRandomPosition
    mirrorType = pickRandomType

    if (verifyPosition(mirrorLocation, mirrorType)):
       i = i - 1
       next
    else:
       storeMirror(mirrorLocation, mirrorType)
```

In verifyPosition, we test the mirror that it reaches a laser in all four directions, in hope of avoiding undetectedable mirrors. It is somewhat boring code, so I omit it here.

Comment: what's the question - your algorithm works

Comment: It is so damn slow :(. I have to limit the number of retries on it, otherwise it'll take ages to generate a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make sure it's not trying multiple fields more than once is to iterate over the fields and put a mirror or not based on some probability. The probability to put a mirror should be #mirros / #fields, so that the expected number of mirrors is #mirrors at the end.